# Excel - List all the combinations of two words from one list, in two other columns

Tags: excel, combinations

I have a list of names in column A and I want to list all the combinations (not permutations) of these in columns C and D. I.e. for 8 names I should have 28 combinations listed in columns C and D. I don't know how to use VBA at all so a simple step by step guide would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> and when the VBE opens, immediately use the pull-down menus to Insert ► Module (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>M</kbd>). Paste the following into the new pane titled something like *Book1 - Module1 (Code)*,

```
Sub name_by_name()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, lr As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lr
            For j = i + 1 To lr
                .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
                  .Cells(i, 1).Value & ", " & .Cells(j, 1).Value
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

I imagined that your name list started in row 2 (with A1 as a header label). If the names start in A1, change `For i = 2 To lr` to `For i = 1 To lr`. I also separated the combined names with a <kbd>space</kbd><kbd>comma</kbd>. Change that three lines further down if you like. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to return to your worksheet. Tap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to open the **Macros** dialog and <kbd>Run</kbd> the macro. Your results should be similar to the following.

[image: Combined Names]